# QT Jambi on Mac installation fail

Tags: java, qt, qt-jambi

I tried installing QT Jambi 4.7.0 on Mac but I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
>   com.trolltech.qt.QtJambiObject.(QtJambiObject.java:60) Caused
>   by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Loading library failed, progress so
>   far: Unpacking .jar file: 'qtjambi-macosx-gcc-4.7.0.jar' Checking
>   Archive 'qtjambi-macosx-gcc-4.7.0.jar'
>    - cache key='gcc-20101012-2105'
>    - adding 'libQtCore.4.dylib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libQtCore.4.dylib', 
>    - adding 'libQtGui.4.dylib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libQtGui.4.dylib', 
>    - adding 'libQtXml.4.dylib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libQtXml.4.dylib', 
>    - adding 'libQtSql.4.dylib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libQtSql.4.dylib', 
>    - adding 'libQtSvg.4.dylib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libQtSvg.4.dylib', 
>    - adding 'libQtNetwork.4.dylib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libQtNetwork.4.dylib', 
>    - adding 'libQtHelp.4.dylib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libQtHelp.4.dylib', 
>    - adding 'libQtScript.4.dylib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libQtScript.4.dylib', 
>    - adding 'libQtScriptTools.4.dylib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libQtScriptTools.4.dylib', 
>    - adding 'libQtMultimedia.4.dylib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libQtMultimedia.4.dylib', 
>    - adding 'libQtOpenGL.4.dylib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libQtOpenGL.4.dylib', 
>    - adding 'libQtWebKit.4.dylib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libQtWebKit.4.dylib', 
>    - adding 'libQtXmlPatterns.4.dylib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libQtXmlPatterns.4.dylib', 
>    - adding 'libphonon.4.dylib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libphonon.4.dylib', 
>    - library: name='plugins/phonon_backend/libphonon_qt7.dylib', never load
>    - library: name='plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib', never load
>    - library: name='plugins/imageformats/libqgif.dylib', never load
>    - library: name='plugins/imageformats/libqmng.dylib', never load
>    - library: name='plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.dylib', never load
>    - library: name='plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.dylib', never load
>    - library: name='plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.dylib', never load
>    - library: name='plugins/codecs/libqcncodecs.dylib', never load
>    - library: name='plugins/codecs/libqjpcodecs.dylib', never load
>    - library: name='plugins/codecs/libqkrcodecs.dylib', never load
>    - library: name='plugins/codecs/libqtwcodecs.dylib', never load
>    - library: name='plugins/accessible/libqtaccessiblewidgets.dylib', never load
>    - adding 'libqtjambi.jnilib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libqtjambi.jnilib', 
>    - adding 'libcom_trolltech_qt_core.jnilib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libcom_trolltech_qt_core.jnilib', 
>    - adding 'libcom_trolltech_qt_gui.jnilib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libcom_trolltech_qt_gui.jnilib', 
>    - adding 'libcom_trolltech_qt_xml.jnilib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libcom_trolltech_qt_xml.jnilib', 
>    - adding 'libcom_trolltech_qt_sql.jnilib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libcom_trolltech_qt_sql.jnilib', 
>    - adding 'libcom_trolltech_qt_help.jnilib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libcom_trolltech_qt_help.jnilib', 
>    - adding 'libcom_trolltech_qt_script.jnilib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libcom_trolltech_qt_script.jnilib', 
>    - adding 'libcom_trolltech_qt_scripttools.jnilib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libcom_trolltech_qt_scripttools.jnilib', 
>    - adding 'libcom_trolltech_qt_multimedia.jnilib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libcom_trolltech_qt_multimedia.jnilib', 
>    - adding 'libcom_trolltech_qt_svg.jnilib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libcom_trolltech_qt_svg.jnilib', 
>    - adding 'libcom_trolltech_qt_opengl.jnilib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libcom_trolltech_qt_opengl.jnilib', 
>    - adding 'libcom_trolltech_qt_network.jnilib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libcom_trolltech_qt_network.jnilib', 
>    - adding 'libcom_trolltech_qt_phonon.jnilib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libcom_trolltech_qt_phonon.jnilib', 
>    - adding 'libcom_trolltech_qt_webkit.jnilib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libcom_trolltech_qt_webkit.jnilib', 
>    - adding 'libcom_trolltech_qt_xmlpatterns.jnilib' to library map
>    - library: name='lib/libcom_trolltech_qt_xmlpatterns.jnilib', 
>    - plugin path='plugins'
>    - using cache directory: '/var/folders/jq/vjb1r8w94vs4z3ysdx8b2c1h0000gn/T/QtJambi_jop_x86_64_4.7.0_gcc-20101012-2105'
>    - cache directory exists Loading library: 'libQtCore.4.dylib'...
>    - using deployment spec
>
> at
>   com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadNativeLibrary(NativeLibraryManager.java:431)
>     at
>   com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadQtLibrary(NativeLibraryManager.java:356)
>     at com.trolltech.qt.Utilities.loadQtLibrary(Utilities.java:145)     at
>   com.trolltech.qt.Utilities.loadQtLibrary(Utilities.java:141)  at
>   com.trolltech.qt.QtJambi_LibraryInitializer.(QtJambi_LibraryInitializer.java:56)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /private/var/folders/jq/vjb1r8w94vs4z3ysdx8b2c1h0000gn/T/QtJambi_jop_x86_64_4.7.0_gcc-20101012-2105/lib/libQtCore.4.dylib:
>   dlopen(/private/var/folders/jq/vjb1r8w94vs4z3ysdx8b2c1h0000gn/T/QtJambi_jop_x86_64_4.7.0_gcc-20101012-2105/lib/libQtCore.4.dylib,
>   1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /private/var/folders/jq/vjb1r8w94vs4z3ysdx8b2c1h0000gn/T/QtJambi_jop_x86_64_4.7.0_gcc-20101012-2105/lib/libQtCore.4.dylib:
>   mach-o, but wrong architecture    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1843)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)     at
>   java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:783)  at
>   com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadLibrary_helper(NativeLibraryManager.java:458)
>     at
>   com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadNativeLibrary(NativeLibraryManager.java:426)
>     ... 5 more

How to fix?

Comment: I’d guess the archs that build was built for does not include arch of your mac. We’d (the jambi project) would really need someone to give some love for mac side, so unless someone else can jump in and tell some magic fix, please try to investigate it by yourself and contribute your findings :)